# Wierd bar appearing on screen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar, fullscreen, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell Optiplex 3050 with W10x64 Pro, nothing fancy. But every so often a bar appears in maximized programs. It is at the bottom, and it starts between the taskbar and overlaps the maximized window. It starts to cut off the bottom of the maximized app, and slowly grows throughout the day. The bar appears to show the window behind it, and clicking on it will select the program behind the current one. If I right click I can get the right click menu for the window behind. If it is the desktop behind the app, I get the right click menu for the desktop. Depending on the program window behind the current one, the bar will appear as either white, black, grey, or the desktop background.

This is very odd, as I have recently purchased a 2nd Optiplex 3050 to replace this one, and it started on the new one as well. I have other Dell Optiplex 3050's that this does not happen to.

[calc.exe with the bar overlapping the bottom row of buttons](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahhvdnf443x6ifr/IMG_2347.png?dl=0)

[Chrome with bar showing at the bottom](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f602en5p2njmk9v/IMG_2349.png?dl=0)

[Chrome with bar showing at the bottom](https://www.dropbox.com/s/546a5wn7xyolh78/IMG_2351.png?dl=0)

[Explorer with bar illustrating the cutting off of window contents](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1t3m2rqzygjhace/IMG_2353.png?dl=0)

[Illustrating right clicking on bar pulls menu from the window behind current](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm52sdd5iwg2f0l/IMG_2355.png?dl=0)

[calc.exe Illustrating bar is only present while maximized](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eeitwcrxf3yxs6l/IMG_2356.png?dl=0)

I have noticed that in chrome if you go full screen with F11 and then back to just maximized, the bar disappears for chrome but is still there for other programs. 
Also, new tabs of chrome bring the bar back. 
Also, it doesn't appear that word is affected by the bar.

The Optiplex 3050 has an i5-7500 with integrated graphics. I have reformatted windows to stock, and installed all of the windows & driver updates that I can find.

I am at a loss as to why this is happening & I suspect that Dell is going to pawn this off on Windows since it happened on more than 1 distinct computers.

Comment: Also, I should note that this computer has 2 monitors, I tried switching the monitors and cables and it is always on the same monitor that this occurs. That initially led me to suspect the HDMI port, but since it is happening with a brand new computer as well, I am not as sure.

Comment: Working with Dell Pro Support, the replaced motherboards and have determinied that they believe this is a Windows 10 issue.

Comment: I am inclined to believe them because I had a user report this happening on an HP laptop as well. But only once a few months ago. Other than that this is a daily occurrence on all new Dell Optiplex 3050 SFF's we have purchased & a Dell Vostro 15, but does not appear on any of the older Optiplex 3020 SFF's that we have in use. Both use the same Windows 10 version, which makes me think it might be a windows issue, but one in combination with certain newer hardware in use in the Optiplex 3050's.